# How to use .html?q= as link shortener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

so i was wondering is there a way to make a simple javascript shortener like I manually enter the code for javascript. Like This:

```
If I have a function 12345 {
window.location.href = "http://link.com";
}
```

12345 being code
and when you type

```
http://example.com/index.html?q=12345
```

it redirects to the http://link.com
no php please

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you possibly phrase it differently?

Comment: You mean like a page ID feature? Like `http://example.com/?p=1351` or `?id=1351` or so redirecting to a specific article? This can be done with a JavaScript object: `var redirections = {"1": "article-1.html", "2": "article-2.html"};` Then you just need to extract the value from the URL query, check whether that object `hasOwnProperty` of that ID and then redirect it to the respective page.

Comment: @Xufox yes like that but with external links

Comment: @brendan Just generalize this concept to external links.

Comment: @Xufox thank you for the advice if I can't figure it out I'll comment back

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code

```
 window.location.search.replace("?", "");
```

to find the value that has been passed to GET in the header. From here, you could delimit the `q=` and get the value for the page you want to view. From here, you could check out [this blog](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) on Github for how to edit the URI. Alternatively, you could check out check out [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)